# Why won't some appliances turn on after garbage disposal replacement?

Tags: electrical, dishwasher, hood

I recently had the garbage disposal replaced (connects to an outlet under the sink) and in less than two weeks, the dishwasher (hardwired) and microwave/hood stopped working and no lights appear.

The plumber who completed the garbage disposal unit replacement came back to take a look.  He tried resetting the breaker and tested the wiring in the dishwasher's junction box and confirmed there was power.  He also stated that the garbage disposal unit and dishwasher ran off the same circuit so it was likely a broken dishwasher.  I also verified the outlet for the microwave/hood and it was able to charge a phone.

Could this be an electrical issue or two fairly old appliances coincidentally dying around the same time?

Comment: What voltages do the dishwasher, mwave and garbage unit run on?

Comment: It could be the GFCI that is sometimes hard to reset.

Comment: Verify that the neutral to both appliances is complete as well.  As asked above, look at what voltage you have between the hot and neutrals at both appliances.  You could have an open neutral.

Comment: Are the microwave & hood on the same circuit as the dishwasher & garbage disposal? If so, that _may_ be a code violation (not sure on all the details of hard-wired appliances). To directly answer your question, "Yes" - this is an electrical issue or two devices dying at the same time. Depending on what killed the disposal, it could have caused power issues that could also have killed the dishwasher on the same circuit, or electrical issues that first killed the disposal could have killed the washer, but more slowly. Maybe have an electrician check the circuit to see what's wrong.

Comment: It is possible they both died about the same time.  It is also possible to be an electrical problem, which is usually much cheaper to test and fix than buying new stuff to just see if it works.  If the microwave is plugged in,  I would move it to a known working circuit, one that powers a vacuum or similar motor device.  Phone chargers are not the best testers, or plug a vacuum in the microwave receptacle.

Comment: Also, the broken nuke might simply be the internal fuse dying.  Have had that happen before, and a new fuse solved the problem.